# Is "pkginfo" mostly related to Solaris?

Tags: linux, package-management

Is "pkginfo" mostly related to Solaris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, pkginfo is mostly used by Solaris.

Mostly linux distro's use one of the common linux package manager like ubuntu that uses the debian package system, or wrote there own like arch linux that uses pacman

Comment: To clarify, Debian uses the APT collection. Slackware (a Linux distro) uses `pkg` tools that are similar to (and inspired by) Solaris. See here: http://slacksite.com/slackware/packages.html

Comment: To clarify, Debian uses dpkg, APT is a high level tool ontop of it and Solaris uses the pkgadd format (there is another name for this, can't remember now) and yes pkginfo is mostly used by Solaris, but there are some linux and BSD distro's the use it

Comment: @Monkey: You are absolutely right that `dpkg` is a better match for the `pkg` tools than the APT library (since the whole point of APT is dependency tracking, which I think the `pkg` tools don't do though I may be wrong about that - like `dpkg`). I didn't mean to be snarky with 'To clarify', I just wanted to specify the name of Debian's package system.

Comment: :) all good, I didn't see it as being snarky

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no.
The `pkginfo` command and the whole related standard packaging format is an AT&T SVR4.0 Unix feature kept in its descendants. Solaris is however by far the more popular. Other ones include NCR Unix, SCO Unixware, DG/UX and Reliant.